# Chat catching user tags incorrectly

Tags: bug, chat

So I went into the Java chat room and there was someone with the name Michael. Whenever they tag him in any comment, it comes up tagging me as well. It appears as if it's catching a portion of my name rather than the full name. It's annoying to have it keep giving me notifications that are clearly not for me.

The relevant post you provided seems to not address my issue. It claims that the problem is fixed, however, I am clearly getting this issue, proving the opposite. It also appears to suggest that it is on the side of the person tagging a user, however, I want the solution to be on my end, to stop getting notifications that aren't of my full name. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you show us a transcript?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/139

Comment: Do you get a full ping or just the name highlighting?

Comment: It comes up as a notification in my inbox, alongside the colour of the name being highlighted green.